# Adding custom global javascript validation

Tags: magento2, javascript, validation, form-validation, magento-2.0.5

I have done some digging in internet but I haven't found any confirmed solution. What is the way to **add custom js validation rule**, that can be used globally as for example `frontend_class` for attributes or validation classes for form's inputs? It would be the best if I could store it in one of my modules.

By the way, for version 2.05 is there any class validating by min or max lenght of string/number of characters? The ones I have found in net don't work (seems to me they are outdated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you add a validation class via the `frontend_class` let's say "validate-custom-class" you'll need to use the following JS to add a custom validation based on a this class:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){ 
    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-custom-class', function (value) { 
        // Add your validation logic here
        // Needs to return true if validation pass
        // Or false if validation fails
    }, $.mage.__('Field is not valid'));
});
```

Comment: ok and where should put this code? JS file, but where is good place for this? 
If I want to use it in some form I also add only `validate-custom-class` in the way it is done with other validation classes?

Comment: Yes same way as it's done with other validation classes. You place the direct JS in a `<script>` tag below your form or you can put this code in a JS file and include it in your page head tag it's up to you

Comment: is there any recommended way to add it globally, so any of my form or setup script could use this custom one?

Comment: @lord_of_strings well if you add that JS on every page you'll be able to use it globally ;)

Comment: I mean is there any good way to add in one place that I can use it globally.

Comment: @lord_of_strings you can follow this link: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_css_layout_woes or look for "add JS globally Magento 2" on StackExchange