# How to use addfield pattern validation

Tags: magento2, admin, form-validation

I have a custom admin form and unfortunately it doesnt have a UI component xml file.

I was able to add the `no-whitespace` class validation.

I would add also a `regexp pattern`, but I don't know where I should specify the format.

I tried

```
'class' => 'no-whitespace pattern',
'pattern' => '^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$'
```

but only `no-whitespace` works fine

any idea?
tnx

Answer (score 2):

Antonio Pedicini, **instead of  add custom  pattern  direct to input field** ,my suggest to create a `magento 2 create custom validation`

So, extend rules.js to add custom validation rules for this pattern.

First create folder inside at `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`  if its already exist then skip it keep file into below location from core module.

And that files add

```
 "MyCustompattern": [
            function(value) {
                return value.match(/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('My Custom Validaion')
        ],
```

**after**

```
"no-whitespace": [
            function(value) {
                return /^\S+$/i.test(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('No white space please')
        ],
```

Then add **MyCustompattern**  in  `'class' => 'no-whitespace MyCustompattern'`

Final delete all file from `var/view_preprocessed` and `var/cache,`var/page_cache`. Remove`pub/static `folder contents and run deploy command:
for see ,it is working or not.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Or,you can follow below blog for create custom rules

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/

http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-add-new-custom-form-validation/

[Adding custom global javascript validation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121599/adding-custom-global-javascript-validation)

Comment: tnx Amit, but in that case the rule will be site wide? I just need  it on 1 admin form, why do you think is not a good idea to use pattern on the input? Also, do you have any example how to use it? i'm struggling to find any

Comment: Amit, would that solution extend or override the core rule.js so I need to check against any update?